# For loop exceeds the limit when using img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have an `img_urls` array which contains 2 image urls.

I use this array to loop `img` tag and using `for` loop.

But instead of having 2 images, i have 3 images in my output.

This is my code;

```
var img_urls = ["http://i.onionstatic.com/avclub/5648/48/16x9/1200.jpg", "https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/horse-running.jpg"];

  for (i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {
    $("div").append(
      "<div><img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/></div>"
    );
  }
```

So, whats is wrong with my code?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dvcumvny/)

Comment: The added image is wrapped in a `<div>` ;)

Comment: I feel like the first image ;-) Not seeing the problem ...

Comment: @Burak remove `<div>` tag in you `append`  `$("div").append(
      "<img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/>"
    );`

Comment: when you append the first image you create a div in that div the horse is added and the first div is also populated by the horse

Comment: I checked on chrome devtools, your first created div get the first image PLUS an inner div with the second image. I suspect the problem is with your call to this loop...

Comment: Loop is running twice only but since you are adding inside `div`, in second iteration, you have 2 `div`s and image is appended in both. Try proper selector. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dvcumvny/3/)

Comment: Yah, i got it now guys! Thanks.

Comment: Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/dvcumvny/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the first image you generate a new div.
Then the second image if appended to existing divs.
You should have only one destination div. Add an id to the main div:

```
    <div id="container"></div>
```

--

```
var img_urls = ["http://i.onionstatic.com/avclub/5648/48/16x9/1200.jpg", "https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/horse-running.jpg"];

      for (i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {
        $("div#container").append(
          "<div><img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/></div>"
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `selector` i.e. `id` `class` in the main `div` as when the next iteration occurs it contains two `div` in the `body`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvcumvny/2/#&togetherjs=o3tlnncIF8)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have $("div") as selector. So when you append the first image, you also add new div. So the next image is appended to two divs. Probably you can add id to your div, so

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

...

```
$("#test").append
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are appending everything inside the loop.

```
$(function() {

  var img_urls = ["url1", "url2"];


var html= ""
  for (i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {  
   html += "<div><img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/></div>";
  }
    $("div").append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to global div element, you are appending div also, so generated html will append to generated div too.

Here is html,

```
<div class='test'></div>
```

Here is javascript code,

```
$(function() {

var img_urls = ["image_url1", "image_url2"];

var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {
 html +=   "<div><img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/></div>"
}
$("div.test").append(html);
});
```

Please find here [working link](https://jsfiddle.net/dvcumvny/1/) here

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container"></div>

for (var i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {
console.log(img_urls.length)
  $("div#container").append(
    "<div><img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/></div>"
  );
}
```

when you append the first image you create a div in that div the horse is added and the first div is also populated by the horse

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see  [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dvcumvny/8/)

```
  <div></div>


    $(function() {

  var img_urls = ["http://i.onionstatic.com/avclub/5648/48/16x9/1200.jpg", "https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/horse-running.jpg"];

      for (i = 0; i < img_urls.length; i++) {
        $("div").append(
          "<img src=' " + img_urls[i] + "'/> </br>"
        );
      }

    });
```